# VBA Code Returns String as Variable for Range Location

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

A userform appears and the user makes various selections (one of which is the CombobBox_Location) which is then input as a variable; for example "C18"

It is then combined with the strings "Location_" and "UPC_" to create variables that reference named ranges under the same name; so Location_C18 and UPC_C18 are the two named ranges.

I want to reference the range Location_C18 (made up of a lot of cells, not merged) to see if they are all empty.

I also want to set the Combobox_UPC.value to the named range UPC_C18.

When I run the code, I get an error on line `If Range(LocationRow).Value <> 0 Then` ... I would assume it is because I am not correctly writing it. (Normal ranges use the quotation marks, even for named ranges, but as it is a variable I am not sure.)

I have tried to Dim the Row, LocationRow, and UPCRow as ranges and as strings, but had no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Row = ComboBox_Location.Value

    LocationRow = "Location_" & Row
    UPCRow = "UPC_" & Row

        If Range(LocationRow).Value <> 0 Then

            If MsgBox("This row already has data. Are you sure you want to clear it and begin with a new UPC?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

                Range(UPCRow).Value = ComboBox_UPC.Value

                Range(LocationRow).Value = 0

            ElseIf MsgBox("This row already has data. Are you sure you want to clear it and begin with a new UPC?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

                'Do Nothing

            End If

        Else

            Range(UPCRow).Value = ComboBox_UPC.Value

            Range(LocationRow).Value = 0

        End If

    ComboBox_Location.Clear
    ComboBox_UPC.Clear
    Corresponding_Material.Value = ""
    Corresponding_Material_Description.Value = ""

    Change_Material.Hide

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which error and in which line? • Please use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables, then update the code in your question and tell in which line you get which error message.

Comment: Start with Option Explicit and define each of your terms... row, in this case, could be text

Comment: They should be declared as `String` type, because a ComboBox cannot return `Range` objects. Then you need to ensure that the range specified by the combobox & your VBA actually exist, otherwise there will be an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a quick check function to see if the named range exists. Your test of `Range(LocationRow).Value <> 0` will throw an error if that name is not defined.

Try this

```
Public Function NameIsDefined(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim notUsed As Long
    notUsed = Range(name).Rows.Count

    If Err = 1004 Then
        NameIsDefined = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        NameIsDefined = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Next you have to check all the cells in that range for data (presumably from your example that all cells must have a value greater than zero):

```
Public Function CellsHaveData(ByRef dataArea as Range) As Boolean
    CellsHaveData = True
    Dim dataCell As Variant
    For Each dataCell In dataArea
        If dataCell.Value = 0 Then
            '--- if only one cell in the range is not zero, then
            '    we don't have data
            CellsHaveData = False
            Exit Function
        End If           
    Next dataCell
End Function
```

Then your own sub would look like

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Row = ComboBox_Location.Value
    LocationRow = "Location_" & Row
    UPCRow = "UPC_" & Row

    If NameIsDefined(LocationRow) Then
        If Not CellsHaveData(Range(LocationRow)) Then
            Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
            answer = MsgBox("This row already has data. Are you sure you want to " & _
                            "clear it and begin with a new UPC?", vbYesNo)
            If answer = vbYes Then
                Range(UPCRow).Value = ComboBox_UPC.Value
                Range(LocationRow).Value = 0
            ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
                'Do Nothing
            End If
        Else
            Range(UPCRow).Value = ComboBox_UPC.Value
            Range(LocationRow).Value = 0
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Named Range " & LocationRow & " does not exist.", vbOK
    End If

    ComboBox_Location.Clear
    ComboBox_UPC.Clear
    Corresponding_Material.Value = ""
    Corresponding_Material_Description.Value = ""

    Change_Material.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I still recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** the variables.

Comment: I completely agree. Edited and updated. (Assumes `ComboBox_Location` and others are controls with defined names)

Comment: Hi PeterT- thanks so much for coding this out! The only issue I am having is that it is a range that includes multiple cells. I think this is throwing it off because even when they are blank it gives me the are you sure message.

Comment: I only replaced your check for data with a check to see if the named range exists. You needed to perform the check against all the cells in the range to see if they have data. The example has been updated.